# How can I propagate an exit status from Expect to its parent Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect, exit-code

I have a bash script, exec.sh like

```
some command
expect test.exp
continue other command
```

in the test.exp file, I have a snippet like:

```
while {[gets $cmds command]>=0} {
  send "$command\r"
  expect {
    "*OK*" {puts $vout $command}
    "*fail*" {puts $iout $command}
    "*blocked*" { what should I put here????}
    }  
  }
```

so I want to put something in the curly bracket so that the execution exit the test.exp and signal the bash script exec.sh, so exec.sh  also exit
my idea is the set a outer variable and then in exec.sh use "if" judge statement

are there any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### Pass Exit Status from Expect

Tcl (and therefore Expect) have an `exit` command that takes an argument. The argument is the exit status for the process. It's up to you to assign a meaning to an exit status, and to test the exit status from your shell script. For example, using the values from */usr/include/sysexits.h* you could write:

```
expect {
  "blocked" { exit 69 }
}
```

and then test for that value in your script.

#### Branch on Exit Status in Shell

The exit status of the last process is stored in the $? variable. One way to test this would be to use a case statement, and branch accordingly. For example:

```
expect test.exp
case $? in
  69)
    # Handle the exit status, and then propagate the same exit status
    # from the shell script.
    echo 'service unavailable' > /dev/stderr
    exit 69
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: This was very helpful.  My expect script exits with a non-zero when it sees a certain error message.  Exactly what I needed!  Thanks.